# Append the result of calculation to data frame in loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, append

I am trying to do a calculation for each date included in my simulation period, and save the result of each day in a data frame.

This is what I did :

```
SimulPeriod<- subset(HistoriqueNew, HistoriqueNew$Timestamp> DateIni)

  p.and.l <- data.frame("13/3/2014",0)
  names(p.and.l)<-c("DatePL", "PL")
  p.and.l$DatePL<-as.Date(p.and.l$DatePL, "%d-%m/%Y")

  for (p.and.l.date in SimulPeriod$Timestamp) {

    ## simulates closure of the position each day ##

    CompteCourantUSD<-CompteCourantUSDIni+Achetes*SimulPeriod$Trade.Close.y
    CompteCourantGBP<-CompteCourantGBPIni-Vendus*SimulPeriod$Trade.Close.x/100
    ResultatJour <- CompteCourantUSD/SimulPeriod$Bid.Close+CompteCourantGBP

    p.and.l$DatePL <- rbind(p.and.l$DatePL, p.and.l.date)
    p.and.l$PL <- rbind(p.and.l$PL, ResultatJour))
    }
```

I get the following message in the console :

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"    p.and.l$DatePL <- rbind(p.and.l$DatePL, p.and.l.date)
    p.and.l$PL <- rbind(p.and.l$PL, ResultatJour))"
     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
```

Comment: Strangely, I see that the variable ResultatJour is a vector with 279 values, not one value (that of the day within the loop as I expected.

Comment: So it seems that even without cbinding, the ResultatJour vector has all the time serie of daily results which I want...

Comment: Growing an object in a loop is one of the slowest operations you can do in R. You know how big the object needs to be in the end. Pre-allocate it to that size.

Answer (score 0):

You have two enclosing parentheses in :

`p.and.l$PL <- rbind(p.and.l$PL, ResultatJour))`

just replace it with :

`p.and.l$PL <- rbind(p.and.l$PL, ResultatJour)`

Comment: You're right on that one. Sorry, am a beginner. But now I get this message : Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "DatePL", value = c(NA, 16143)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1

Comment: I realise that actually, I don't even need a loop, nor appending my data frame. With vector calculation, I immediately get the column of results which I can cbind to my initial data